# How do I use a button without an ID in a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use a button without an ID in a jQuery function?

example:

[image: example]

function example:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: The cleanest solution is probably to give it an ID. Why can't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
 //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id` of parent and then search necessary element inside it

```
$('#shipping-method-buttons-container>.primary .button.continue')
```

or

```
$('#shipping-method-buttons-container .primary .button.continue')
```

#### Explanation:

- get element by  `#shipping-method-buttons-container`.
- Now in the fetched element, search `.primary` among children. `>` will make it search immediate level. (space) will make it search any level.
- Finally, you have to search for element who has `.button.continue`

Comment: do i use the full button class so: $('#shipping-method-buttons-container .primary .button.action.continue.primary')

Comment: @Callum No. A unique combination. `.primary` is shared between `div` and `button`. `.button` will be shared between multiple buttons. So `.button.continue` can uniquely identify a button in this div. Idea is to create a create a unique selector by merging multiple selectors

Comment: I've used what you told me to use but no alert is appearing

Comment: @Callum can you create a fiddle? I answer based on a basic understanding of how to fetch element. If you only wish to add click handler, you can try `$('#shipping-method-buttons-container').on('click', '.button.continue', function(){})`. If its a dynamically added field, try `$('document').bind('click', '#shipping-method-buttons-container>.primary .button.continue', function(){})`

Comment: Creating a fiddle is a bit tricky because you're looking at magento html

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onclick" function by button.

```
<input type="button" value="" onclick="Blabla()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myButton = $("button[data-role='opc-continue']");
$myButton.on("click", function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

By using the [jQuery select by attribute equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), you can single out the button you need without an `id` and without having to traverse the DOM

Comment: You should add some hints, waht you are doing, not just code.

Comment: please explain how this code solve the problem